# SSIS loses file reference when opening script task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We use a custom audit assembly (C#) for logging several kinds of actions within SSIS in script tasks.

We post build the custom assembly in the GAC (for runtime) and to the public assemblies area of the IDE (VS2008) for design time file referencing. After the postbuild is done the custom assembly is available for use in runtime and for designtime in the .NET tab of the file reference popup.

However, after re-opening the script task, the file reference is gone in the list and the script doesn't compile.

How's that possible ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems liks a bug in SSIS, but I have a workaround here:

Just click Save All instead of just closing the popped up IDE C# editor.

Comment: Had the same when referencing the Excel Interop (don't ask..)

Comment: VB, I don't know