# where did my c# reference go?

Tags: c#, linq, reference, ssis, script-component

I have not seen a question like this so far - I have a script component in an SSIS package.  I have added a few references so far to it.  It seemed to work as expected.  I added `System.Data.Linq` and `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` and it seems to work fine (The colors on the key words change colors, Intellisense red lines go away).  And I close my script and run the package and then it didn't work (but didn't give me an error either)  and I open up the script component and the reference is gone!  I add it, do everything the same, open it back up, and it's gone again!  I dunno whats going on

Comment: Stupid question, but I have to ask: are you saving your changes?

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767558/ssis-loses-file-reference-when-opening-script-task

Comment: Which version of SSIS?

Comment: Im using 2008 and yes I have been saving my changes (pressing CTRL+s), then when I exit from the editor for the component I click te "Exit" icon.

Comment: Dude NoviceProgrammer I missed your help. Ughhhh could have saved so much time.  Thaks a lot though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooooo apparently 'Save All' worked.  Even though I never hit 'Save All' before and I just added System.Core and just saved.  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is after closing the solution (in which I assume that you are saving your  changes) is I will do a file comparison of the project or solution using TFS or VSS. Your changes might not being saved properly OR you might be editing a wrong project.

Comment: but how can i comapre using those things, this is just on my local machine.

Comment: what does that mean - to edit a wrong project?  Open up the script, edit it, close it.  How could I be editing the wrong one?